# Aurelia Validation Rules: Unable to parse accessor function

Tags: aurelia

It seems there have been various problems elsewhere in regards to the `aurelia-validation` module, but I haven't seen anything that has addressed the specific problem I've been running into.

I have a model class with the definition and validation rules as below:

**my-model.js**

```
my-model = {
    "name":
        {
        "full": "",
        "short": "",
        }
    };

...

ValidationRules
    .ensure(model => model.name.full).required().minLength(5).maxLength(50)
    .on(this.my-model);
```

When I try it in the browser, however, I get the error:

```
...
Inner Error:
Message: Unable to parse accessor function:
function (model) {
                        return model.name.full;
                    }
...
```

[This question](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/324) was the closest I was able to see to my problem, and [another here](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/341) seems to be having the same issue.

I am running `aurelia-framework@^1.0.2` and `aurelia-validation@^1.0.0-beta.1.0.1` which I believe are just the defaults from regular updates (but also the reason for it suddenly not working). Is it possible I'm still running incompatible versions of some modules? Or is there somewhere elsewhere in my code that I need to fix?

Comment: I still don't get why your `ensure` didn't work. What was the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you target the property instead of the object? Does that work?

```
myModel = {
  "name": {
    "full": "",
    "short": "",
  }
};

ValidationRules
  .ensure(model => model.full)
    .required()
    .minLength(5)
    .maxLength(50)
  .on(this.myModel.name); //<--- see
```

Comment: So I misread that and tried doing `model.full` without adjusting `.on(this.myModel)` and it worked even with that. I've updated it to it fully as you describe and it is working now. Thank you very much.